# Choose three numbers from a sequence such that their sum is less than a value

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have an sequence of numbers :

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1

I wonder about algorithm which could say 
**how many possible ways of choosing 3 numbers from sequence above exist, such that their sum doesn't exceed 7?**

I was asked to write a program to solve the problem. Are there any program techniques I can use?

I will be appreciate your answer!

Comment: i think it can be reduced to 3-sum problem.

Comment: **-1 for not clear question, and for not clarifying it**. You suggested in [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427985#comment39670998_25428148) that there is no about finding 3 numbers, but about finding how much ways we can choose 3 numbers, but **didn't edited your question to include this information**, so I wasted my time writing useless algorithm. It seems that your question can be make even clearer, but I can't clarify it, because I'm not sure what are you asking about. However, your question is interesting, **I'm going to upvote it when you clarify it enough**.

Comment: dude， maybe i am not got it across.  my objective is to count the total number of ways to choose 3  numbers with distinct index in the sequence,  of course you may have repeated values as long as you keep the indices distinct

Comment: So write it in question, not comments! It's going to be more noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to obtain O(n^2) time complexity using two pointers technique:

1. Sort the numbers.
2. Let's fix the middle number. Let's assume that its index is mid.
3. For a fixed mid, you can maintain two indices: low and high. They correspond to the smallest and the biggest number in a sum. Initially, low = mid - 1 and high = mid + 1.
4. Now you can increment high by one in a loop and decrement low as long as the sum of 3 numbers is greater then S. For a fixed high and mid, low shows how many numbers can added to a[mid] and a[high] so that thier sum is <= S. Note that for a fixed mid, high can be incremented O(n) times and low can be decremented only O(n) times. Thus, time complexity is O(n^2).

This algorithm requires only O(1) additional space(for low, mid and high indices).

Comment: you mean for a fixed mid, you run brute force search to count the candidate choice , that's okay,  but when you have completed for a fixed mid index, you have to  think a way to remove that mid value from your sequence , but then how can you choose the next mid value??

Comment: @Hexinwei 1)For a fixed mix, it is not exactly brute force. Brute force would work O(n^2) for a fixed mix, making the total complexity O(n^3). Two pointers technique is used instead. 2)I simply iterate over all possible mid's(1...n).

Comment: You are right, i have implemented your algorithms in C++， very cool

Answer (score 2):

To get the lowest 3-sum possible, you will simply need to choose the lowest 3 numbers. If this number is lower than the given number - you are done. Otherwise you can answer - there is no such solution, since every other sum you get is bigger than the one you just found, which by its own is bigger than the desired number.

If you wish to find out "How many different summations there are to a number smaller than the given number", that's a different problem, that can be solved using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) in `O(n*number*3) = O(n*number)`:

```
f(x,i,3) = (x <+ 0 ? 0 : 1)
f(_,n,_) = 0 //out of bound
f(x,i,used) = f(x-arr[i],i+1, used + 1) + f(x,i+1,used)
```

Invoke with `f(number,0,0)`

Comment: maybe that's a  good direction for solving this problem,  i will think about it. many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following program written in Python 3.4.1 gives one solution that may help you with the problem.

```py
NUMBERS = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1
TARGET = 7
USING = 3

def main():
    candidates = sorted(NUMBERS)[:USING]
    if sum(candidates) <= TARGET:
        print('Your numbers are', candidates)
    else:
        print('Your goal is not possible.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Edit:**

Based on your comment that you want all possible solutions, the following provides this information along with the number of unique solutions. A solution is considered to be the same as another if both have the same numbers in them (regardless of order).

```py
import itertools

NUMBERS = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1
TARGET = 7
USING = 3

def main():
    # Find all possible solutions.
    solutions = []
    for candidates in itertools.combinations(NUMBERS, USING):
        if sum(candidates) <= TARGET:
            print('Solution:', candidates)
            solutions.append(candidates)
    print('There are', len(solutions), 'solutions to your problem.')
    # Find all unique solutions.
    unique = {tuple(sorted(answer)) for answer in solutions}
    print('However, only', len(unique), 'answers are unique.')
    for answer in sorted(unique):
        print('Unique:', answer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `heapq.nsmallest` is an asymptotically faster alternative to sorting.

Comment: That may be true in theory. However, try running these. Example 1: `timeit.Timer('sorted(NUMBERS)[:USING]', 'NUMBERS = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1; USING = 3').timeit()` Example 2: `timeit.Timer('heapq.nsmallest(USING, NUMBERS)', 'import heapq; NUMBERS = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 1; USING = 3').timeit()` My tests show the former answer to be over 4 times faster.

Comment: Those examples are way too small to show the difference.

Comment: Which is why `heapq.nsmallest` is theoretically faster. With a sufficiently small set of numbers, there are better alternatives. One could write a function that selected the best implementation based on the size of the sequence.

Comment: Amigo, you are partly right, but I think you have missed my point, i need a way to count the total number of the candidate choices. can you think a way to solve this harassing problem

Comment: @Hexinwei The answer has been edited to account for all solutions and unique solutions. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion. A C++ solution:

```
void count(std::vector<int>& arr, int totalTaken, int index, int currentSum, int expectedSum, int *totalSolutions){
        if (index == arr.size()) return;
        if (totalTaken == 3)
            if (currentSum <= expectedSum)
                (*totalSolutions)++;
            else return;
        count(arr, totalTaken++, idex++, curentSum+arr[index],expectedSum, totalSolutions)
        count(arr, totalTaken, index++, currentSum, expectedSum, totalSolutions)
    }
```

Call with `count(your_vector,0,0,0,expectedSum,ptr2int)` after the function has exectuted, you will have your result stored in `*ptr2int`